# Trying to track down memory allocation error under archLinux64

Tags: c, linux, windows, malloc

I'm working on getting a midi compiler, PMML, working again. Yes, it's a programming language in its own right that compiles standard midi files. In brief, after getting the program working fine under windows, using both cygwin and minGW, latest versions, I wanted to move on to a linux system to get it working.

Before moving it to the linux system however, some inital patches had to be applied.

1. Move externs of system functions out of local header files in the project, to eliminate type conflicts.
2. Replace these by including system headers, stdlib.h, string.h and in cases where it was needed, errno.h.
3. Also replaced this construct, sys_errlist[errno] with strerror(errno). This enabled the package to compile quite cleanly under windows, and work.

I chose arch Linux 64-bit, running under VMWare player 6.0.2 in windows 7 64-bit.
When I moved the sources to arch, they compiled fine, but then failed at the test suite, giving a segfault. Subsequent poking about with gdb revealed that somehow, a function is getting bad memory, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it's doing this. I understand that windows and Linux allocate memory differently, but just can't see why the problem's showing up. Any help tracking this down would be appreciated. 
The sources I'm working with are here. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3051632/pmml-0.2p2.tar.gz

Thanks!

edit. seems that after eying the code for a while, the answers just smacked me in the face... One of those really simple things. Seems that in the function __get_expression(), where the program segfaulted, the reason it crashed was... a simple unassigned variable problem that the compile didn't catch. Now, to figure out what to pass to the function to get it working.

Comment: You have to be more specific about the problem you encountered and the problematic function if you want to get some help here...

Comment: You should definitely change your coding style. `Object * _get_expression(asgn_op_type, lopd)` // `int  asgn_op_type;` // `Object *lopd;` is nowadays written as `Object * _get_expression(int asgn_op_type, Object *lopd)`. (But this has been the case only for 24 years, so maybe not everyone has noticed it till now.) It gains you even a certain level of type-safety!

Comment: And, if `_get_expression()` is defined to have 2 parameters, what on earth are you expecting from `#define get_expression() _get_expression(0)`? I am not surprised that you get segfaults... and `Object *_get_expression();` is probably going to fall onto your feet very soon.

Comment: oh, I know, I hate this coding style. But, it wasn't my code to begin with. Yes, forgot to make that clear in the op. I mean, really? Even in 1998, when this code was written, this would have been considered bad code... *shrug*.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) . It is the best linux tool to track memory problems.

All you have to do is run your application via valgrnid:

```
# valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./your_app
```